# Unable to save video while applying filter using MovieOutput in Gpuimage2

Tags: swift, video-processing, gpuimage

i have created video Filter demo, i am apply video filter successfully while video is play but i am unable to save video to local path. in local only gray image saved.

**Below is my sample**

```
let finalpath = "(FileManager.default.finalCompositions)/composition(getTimeStamp).mp4"
let finalUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: finalpath)
print("Final url :: (finalUrl)")

let movieURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "mp4")

let asset: AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(url: movieURL!)
let asetTrack: AVAssetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]

let exportedMovieFile = try! MovieInput(url: movieURL!, playAtActualSpeed: false)
exportedMovieFile.runBenchmark = true

let exportfilter = BrightnessAdjustment()
exportfilter.brightness = 0.5
exportedMovieFile.addTarget(exportfilter)


let exportedMovieWritter = try! MovieOutput(URL: finalUrl, size: Size(width: Float(asetTrack.naturalSize.width), height: Float(asetTrack.naturalSize.height)))

exportfilter.addTarget(exportedMovieWritter)

//Configure this for video from the movie file, where we want to preserve all video frames and audio samples


exportedMovieWritter.startRecording()
exportedMovieFile.start()



exportedMovieWritter.finishRecording {
    exportfilter.removeAllTargets()
    exportedMovieFile.removeAllTargets()
}
```